# jQuery - Select elements by value from array of values

Tags: jquery

Given some simple JSON:

```
["62689", "62690", "62697"]
```

I need to select the three elements in the DOM that correspond to these values (based on `value` attribute). They could be a `<select>`, `<input>`, `<option>` or anything really.

What selector should I be using for this?

Comment: That's more like a simple array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

> *Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.*

For example to select the element whose `value` is `62689`, you'd use:

```
$('[value="62689"]')
```

To select all three, you'd use:

```
$('[value="62689"], [value="62690"], [value="62697"]')
```

If you want to apply some method to these elements and you have more or less than those exact three values, you can just loop through your JSON response and apply accordingly:

```
var data = ["62689", "62690", "62697"];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    $('[value="' + data[i] + '"]');
```

Or you can just pull them all into an array using [jQuery's `map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var elements = $('input, select').map(function() {
    if ($.inArray(this.value, data) != -1)
        return this;
    return false;
}).get();
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to select all three elements, not just one.

Comment: then use foreach loop

Comment: @LorDex why is a loop required?

Comment: actually it's not. your way is better :)

Comment: @LorDex I've added a bit about loops anyway to make the answer more... robust.

Comment: Nice answer! But you have to return `$.inArray() > -1` for it to work  properly

Comment: @Spokey well spotted!

Comment: Consider I will need to bind the same event to all of these elements which makes it tricky due to `<option>` being a possible element.

Comment: @pspahn your select element's `value` property will be equal to the value of the option you've selected. Here's a JSFiddle demo which shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/74hz1b35. If you select "Three" from the list, the `select` element will be given a red background.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly - I guess in this case, I was coming with the wrong approach. Legit answer though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need a forEach loop and a [Attribute selectors - CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)  declare your array like this

markup

```
<input type=text value=62689 />
<input type=text value=62690 />
<input type=text value=62697 />
```

script

```
var selectedArray = ["62689", "62690", "62697"];

selectedArray.forEach(function(e){
    $('[value='+e+']').hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hw0o0h5f/)

Or if you need more that one just conbine them like this `$('input[value='+e+'],select#hider option[value='+e+']').attr('selected', 'selected');`

```
<input type=text value=62689 />
<input type=text value=62690 />
<input type=text value=62697 />
<select id="hider" value=626973>
    <option value=62689>Show</option>
    <option>Hide</option>
</select>
```

script

```
var selectedArray = ["62689", "62690", "62697"];

selectedArray.forEach(function(e){
    $('input[value='+e+'],select#hider option[value='+e+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hw0o0h5f/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this. :

```
var array = ["62689", "62690", "62697"];
$("SelectControl").filter(function() {    
    return jquery.inArray($(this).val(), array) > -1;
})
```

Comment: Same thing here, you have to use `$.inArray() > -1` because the function returns in index of the value and since indexes are 0 based it will return false if the value found has the index 0 even though it was clearly found in the array!

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

For this case I would use something like

```
$('[value="' + items[0] + '"]')
```

Where `items` is the array result from your JSON.