# Set color for the selected option of an HTML Select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selected

In my HTML, I have a `<select>` with many `<option>` elements. I want to use jQuery to check each option's value against a Javascript variable. If one matches, I want to set a color of that option. How would I do that?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood from your requirement, you should try following,

```
var yourVar = 1; //consider your expected value;
$(document).on('change', '#selectId', function(){

   var currentValue = $(this).val();
   if(yourVar == currentValue)
   {
        //apply your colour logic
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a plain html list, not a jQuery UI one then that's all:

```js
var found = $('#cars option[value="saab"]');//Search for 'saab' value
found.css("color","red");//Set color as red
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: if the value is array ,for example  I want to set red for Volvo and Saab option,How should I do it using each?

Comment: @Yao, one way to do that is by `$('#cars option[value="saab"],[value="volvo"]');` or check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301547/jquery-select-elements-by-value-from-array-of-values

Answer (score 0):

You can catch which option you've selected from jquery, from the `$(select).find('option:selected')`, another way is the `$(select).val()` (It'll returns the value of select).

But to style the select element is not possible, checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-a-html-select)